# Select Multiple Id's in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am Totally new to programming , Please help me with below code.

```
<body>
<p>
<select id="Ultra" onchange="">
 <option value="A">A</option>
 <option value="B">B</option>
 <option value="C">C</option>
 </select>
</p>
<p>
<select id="Ultra"  onchange="showData()">
          <option value="0">1</option>
          <option value="1">2</option>
          <option value="2.0">3</option>
          <option value="3.0">4</option>
      </select>
</p>
<p id="data">
 <script>


  function showData()
{
  var data =[[0,23,A],[1,33,B],[2,44,c],[3,55,D]];
  var html = "";
  var x = new Array();
   x = document.querySelectorAll("Ultra")
  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) 
  {
    if(data[i][0]== x[1])
    {
    html = data[i][1] ;
   }
   }
  document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = html;
}
 </script>
 </p>
 </body>
```

I was creating Two Dropdowns with the same ID's , after that I want to retrieve the value for Second Select ID only..

Intentionally , I haven't written any function for first Select, I was just checking querySelectorAll method

In the First Iteration, I was selecting "1" in the dropdown ,
x[1] means numbers Select ID = 0
data[i][0] = 0

I was expecting the output as 23..
But , It was not working !!

Am I done anything wrong using querySelectorAll Method ?

Comment: ID of an element must be unique

Comment: After that , How can I pass those values into querySelectorAll

Comment: instead of giving multiple IDs, try giving same class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Id of an element must be unique, don't use duplicate ID's in your page.

For your problem, you can pass the changed element reference as a param to the method like

```
<p>
    <select class="Ultra" onchange="">
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
    </select>
</p>
<p>
    <select class="Ultra" onchange="showData(this)">
        <option value="0">1</option>
        <option value="1">2</option>
        <option value="2.0">3</option>
        <option value="3.0">4</option>
    </select>
</p>
<p id="data"></p>
```

then

```
function showData(el) {
    var data = [
        [0, 23, 'A'], //the string literals like `A` must be enclosed in '' or ""
        [1, 33, 'B'],
        [2, 44, 'c'],
        [3, 55, 'D']
    ];
    var html = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i][0] == el.value) { //need to test against the value of the select
            html = data[i][1];

        }
    }
    document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = html;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r1q8u5zp/)

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `id` attribute with `class`.

```
class = "Ultra"
```

It will work.

Comment: I have tried class="Ultra" after that using the method getElementsByClassName("Ultra").

Comment: In which browser you are testing ? getElementsByClassName will not work for IE < 9

Answer (score 1):

```js
function showData()
{
   
  var data =[[0,23,'A'],[1,33,'B'],[2,44,'c'],[3,55,'D']];
  var html = "";
  var x = new Array();
   x = document.querySelectorAll("#Ultra")
  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) 
  {
    if(data[i][0]== x[1].value)
    {
    html = data[i][1] ;
   }
   }
  document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = html;
}
```

Changes to be made:
1)querySelectorAll('#ultra') 
2)x[1].value

This works